# Get multiplication table generalized for n dimensions with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Let `a = np.arange(1, 4)`.

To get the 2 dimensional multiplication table for `a`, I do:

```
>>> a * a[:, None]      
>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 4, 6],
           [3, 6, 9]])
```

For 3 dimensions, I can do the following:

```
>>> a * a[:, None] * a[:, None, None] 
>>> array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
            [ 2,  4,  6],
            [ 3,  6,  9]],

           [[ 2,  4,  6],
            [ 4,  8, 12],
            [ 6, 12, 18]],

           [[ 3,  6,  9],
            [ 6, 12, 18],
            [ 9, 18, 27]]])
```

How could I write a function that takes a numpy array `a` and a number of dimensions `n` as input and ouputs the `n` dimensional multiplication table for `a`?

Comment: Play with `np.expand_dims`.  Or `np.ix_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
import itertools
a = np.arange(1, 4)
n = 3

def f(x, y):
    return np.expand_dims(x, len(x.shape))*y

l = list(itertools.accumulate(np.repeat(np.atleast_2d(a), n, axis=0), f))[-1]
```

Just change `n` to be whatever dimension you need

Answer (score 0):

First we can use [`numpy.expand_dims()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) for dynamically *promoting* the array dimensions as needed in a list/generator comprehension and then use an iterable product tool such as `math.prod` on Python 3.8+. The implementation would then look like as demonstrated below:

```
from math import prod

def n_dim_multiplication(arr, num_dims):
    gen_arr = (np.expand_dims(a, axis=tuple(range(1, idx+1))) for idx in range(num_dims))
    return prod(gen_arr)
```

Sample run for the 3 dimensional case:

```
# input array
In [83]: a = np.arange(1, 4)

# desired number of dimensions
In [84]: num_dims = 3

In [85]: n_dim_multiplication(a, num_dims)
Out[85]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 2,  4,  6],
        [ 3,  6,  9]],

       [[ 2,  4,  6],
        [ 4,  8, 12],
        [ 6, 12, 18]],

       [[ 3,  6,  9],
        [ 6, 12, 18],
        [ 9, 18, 27]]])
```